# How to display an alert inside a dialog ionic 4

Tags: javascript, ionic4

I'm using ionic 4, I have the page displayed as dialog, inside the dialog I have a button, when I click the button an alert displayed on the screen.

My problem is when the alert display the dialog disappeared, but I want to keep the dialog displayed, how to achieve that please.

heres the code the alert inside the button:

```
   async deletStations() {
     const alert = await this.alertController.create({
        header: 'Alert',
       subHeader: 'Subtitle',
       message: 'This is an alert message.',
       buttons: ['OK']
     });
   }
```

Comment: Can you please share the implementation of the dialog too?

Comment: Why do you have an alert inside a dialog? You need a dialog for some reason?